# why do my various user programs terminate abruptly without an error message?

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-18.04

I do a variety of different kinds of data analysis and numerical simulation on my custom-built Ubuntu machine using custom-written programs that sometimes must run for days or even weeks.  Some of those programs have been in Fortran, some in Python, some in C; there is literally zero commonality between these programs except that they run a long time and do a lot of disk i/o. Most are single-thread.

The typical execution command line looks like

```
./myprog &> myprog.log &
```

If an ordinary runtime error occurs, any buffered program output and the error message both faithfully appear in `myprog.log` and the logfile is cleanly closed.  But what's been happening instead in many cases is that the program simply quits in mid-stream -- usually after half a day to a day or so, without any further output to the log file.   It's like the program had been randomly hit with a 'kill -9'.

I don't know why this is happening, and it seems to be specific to this particular machine (I have been doing similar work for 30 years and never experienced this before).   The operating system itself seems rock-stable; it has been rebooted only rarely over the past couple years for specific reasons like updates.  It's only my longer-running user processes that seem to die abruptly like this with no accompanying diagnostic.

Not being a system-level expert, I'm at a loss for how to diagnose what's going on.  Right now, my only option is to regularly check whether my program is still running and restart it if necessary.

System details:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Linux kernel: 4.15.0-39-generic
CPU: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950x
```

---

UPDATE: Since `dmesg` was mentioned, here are some representive messages, which I have no idea how to interpret.  The `UFW BLOCK` messages are by far the most numerous, but there are also a fair number of the `ata6` messages, which seem to have something to do with the SATA hard drive.  Could this be relevant?

```
[5301325.692596] audit: type=1400 audit(1594876149.572:218): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" name="/usr/share/locale/" pid=19663 comm="cups-browsed" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0


[5352288.689739] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[5352288.689753] ata6.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 14 pio 16392 in
                          Get event status notification 4a 01 00 00 10 00 00 00 08 00res 40/00:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[5352288.689756] ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
[5352288.689760] ata6: hard resetting link
[5352289.161877] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[5352289.166076] ata6.00: configured for PIO0
[5352289.166635] ata6: EH complete


[5353558.066052] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp5s0 OUT= MAC=10:7b:44:93:2f:58:b4:0c:25:e0:40:12:08:00 SRC=172.105.89.161 DST=144.92.130.162 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=50780 PROTO=TCP SPT=58944 DPT=68 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Comment: `ata6.00: exception Emask`... there is a problem with your hard drive, inspect it, check `smartctl`, etc. `Could this be relevant?` Is it running on raid so that data consistency is (for 100%) preserved?

Comment: It's not on a raid.  Just one of three standalone disks.

Comment: No logged system error (via dmesg) or smartcl message corresponding even roughly to the time my most recent program run quit.  Back to square one.